# Получить координату индекса у эффекта Line. Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

В **Unity** есть эффект **Line**. Я знаю, как задать позицию индексов данного эффекта:

```
public LineRenderer line;

line.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
line.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(5, 5, 5));
```

Но вот как получить позицию у определённого индекса я не понимаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить позицию координаты y, например, у индекса 1?

Comment: line.GetPosition https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.GetPosition.html

Comment: @Andrey, да я понимаю, что надо использовать данное выражение, но я не понимаю как. К примеру, вот так line.GetPosition(1, position.y) у меня не выходит.

Comment: синтаксис этого метода другой. Он принимает ТОЛЬКО индекс.  И возвращает вектор.

Comment: @Andrey, точно! Я понял как: line.GetPosition(1).y. Спасибо!